# Redirecting stderr and stdout separately to a function in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, logs, io-redirection, systemd-journald

I'm working on [a wrapper script](https://gist.github.com/JadedDragoon/08fcef6b95669cbbfdd436890332a92e) to log cronjob output to journald.

I have several goals:

- must log stderr and stdout to journald with different priority levels and prefix-tags
- must also output stderr of the wrapped command to stderr of the wrapper script (to be caught by cron and emailed in an alert)
- must preserve line order throughout

So far I seem to have two problems:

1. I'm not sure how to redirect stderr and stdout separately to my logging function. Everything I've tried thus far fails to redirect anything more than NULL. In my defense, redirection is not one of my strong points. **(Resolved, see comments)**
2. My current approach `{ $_EXEC $_ARGS 2>&1 1>&7 7>&- | journaldlog error; } 7>&1 1>&2 | journaldlog info` appears to run the logging function exactly twice, once for stderr and once for stdout. This will not preserve line order. I would rather it run the function once per output line.

Should I just give up on doing this in bash and try Perl instead? I'm sure my Perl experience would come back to me... eventually.

I've tried a lot of different approaches. Most of which found online and, in particular, on stack exchange. I honestly can't remember what else I've tried... it's just a blur at this point. And the bash docs haven't been much help either.

Comment: I've updated the gist. I've resolved the issue with the function receiving NULL as it's second parameter. Turns out I misunderstood the docs and can't use params for this. I'm now using $(cat) to read stdin in the function.

Answer (score 9):

You can just use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) directly in the redirections:

```
gen > >(one) 2> >(two)
```

That will give the standard output of `gen` as the standard input to `one` and the standard error of `gen` as the input to `two`. Those could be executable commands or functions; here are the functions I used:

```
one() {
    while read line
    do
        echo $'\e[31m'"$line"$'\e[22m'
    done
}

two() {
    while read line
    do
        echo $'\e[32m'"$line"$'\e[22m'
        echo "$line" >&2
    done
}
```

They output their input lines in red and green respectively, and `two` also writes to ordinary standard error. You could do whatever you wanted inside the loops, or send the input on to another program or whatever you required.

---

Note that **there's not really any such thing as "preserving line order" once you're at this point** - they're two separate streams and separate processes, and it's quite possible that the scheduler runs one process for a while before it gives the other one a go, with the data kept in the kernel pipe buffer until it's read. I've been using a function outputting odd numbers to stdout and even to stderr to test with, and it's common to get a run of a dozen or more in a row from each.

It would be possible to get something closer to the ordering as it appears in the terminal, but probably not in Bash. A C program using [`pipe`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html) and [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) could reconstruct an ordering (though still not guaranteed to be the same as displayed, for the same reason: your process might not be scheduled for a while and once there's a backlog, there's no telling what came first<sup>1</sup>). If the ordering is vitally important you'll need another approach, and likely the coöperation of the base executable. If it's a hard requirement you may need to reconsider.

<sup>1</sup><sub>There may also be platform-specific methods for controlling the pipe buffering, but they're unlikely to help you enough either. On Linux, you can shrink the buffer size as low as the system page size but no lower. I don't know of one that lets you force writes through immediately (or blocks until they're read). In any case, they could well be buffered on the source end in the fashion of stdio streams and then you'd never see an ordering.</sub>

Comment: The issue here is if I have... say... a mailer daemon log, and I have 5 messages saying `user connected from x.x.x.x` or whatever. But then I have an error that says `unreadable data` or some such... it would be _really_ helpful to know which of those connections the "unreadable data" is closest to when debugging. If I can't even remotely count on related error and non-error output to be close to each other then I'm losing a significant tool in my problem-solving toolkit. For that matter, how does the terminal/shell/cron manage this? Aren't they working with the same output?

Comment: Writes to one file are ordered; writes to two different pipes read by two different processes aren’t (usefully). Your tool was lost as soon as you split them up.

Comment: But you're saying this can't be done even in a language that is compiled to machine code. That it's fundamentally impossible to spawn another application as a child process and read that child process' stdout and stderr in a predictable order... but then you say writing to a single file is ordered. What's doing the writing? Magic? There is a miscommunication here. Cause what I'm understanding you to say is self-contradictory.

Comment: If standard error and standard output are the same file, they are the same file. Two writes to the same file are ordered, or else files would be useless. If they are not the same file, they are different files with no relationship to each other. When you read from two different files there is no connection between what you get from one and the other, and when you do anything in two different processes there is no fixed ordering of events between them.

Comment: Why do I have to use two different processes? Two different files? These are not requirements I set. Where do they come from?

Comment: Two different files is absolutely a requirement you set, as a fundamental part of the task at hand, so I suppose that one comes from you.

Comment: Two different reading processes isn’t required, as I said, but a single reading process doesn’t actually resolve the issue so it’s perhaps a red herring; there are always separate writing and reading processes, and that’s enough for the scheduler to intervene.

Comment: It's not my intent to output anything to _any_ file. There are three bullet points in the OP that outline my requirements... and they don't mention files anywhere. This _was_ a miscommunication. You've made it into something else. Something I don't have time for.

Comment: Standard input and standard output are the files in question. If you want them separated, you want two files, one for each; if they’re going to the (same) TTY, they’re both one and the same. If you *don’t* want them separated this is all much easier, but it’s definitely been my reading of the question & your code that you did. I’m not really interested in continuing this, so good luck with solving your problem. You might want to ask another question that’s more fine-grained if you have something else in mind.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of capturing *stdout* and *stderr* to different command pipelines.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
exec 3>&1 4>&2

loggerForStdout() {
    # FD 3 is the original stdout
    local x
    while IFS= read -r x; do printf "STDOUT\t%s\n" "$x"; done >&3
}
loggerForStderr() {
    # FD 4 is the original stderr
    local x
    while IFS= read -r x; do printf "STDERR\t%s\n" "$x"; done >&4
}


( (
    # This is where your command would be put
    # e.g. stdbuf -oL -eL rsync -a /from /to
    #
    echo this is stdout; echo this is stderr >&2

) | loggerForStdout ) 2>&1 | loggerForStderr
```

I'm not entirely sure whether it's possible to guarantee interleaved line ordering even with `stdbuf -oL -eL`.

You can omit the first three lines if you have alternative loggers. They exist only so that the code is a complete and self-contained example.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all in my case. `logger-for-stout` doesn't get executed. And `logger-for-stderr` is passed NULL as STDIN inspite of me resolving that issue elsewhere. I updated the gist to show how I implemented your suggestion (currently commented out). Perhaps you can explain where I went wrong?

Comment: @CliffArmstrong my mistake. I changed the code I'd used for my initial test, thinking that it was a cleaner solution. Cleaner it might have been, but broken it was, too. I've removed the redirection of _stdout_ after `2>&3`. Please try that.

Comment: In my tests, `this is stdout` was also being sent to `logger-for-stderr`. The fix for that is to use `/dev/tty`  instead of just `echo`ing  to stdout without redirections.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy thank you for that. I've revisited the code and I believe the result is shorter and cleaner than my original. (And as accurate as yours.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I am using to redirect separately stderr and stdout to a function:

```
tag() { awk '$0="['$1'] "$0; fflush();' ; }

{
    {
        echo std1; sleep 0.1;
        echo error2 >&2; sleep 0.1;
        echo error3 >&2; sleep 0.1;
        echo std4; sleep 0.1;
    } 2>&1 1>&3 | tag STDERR 1>&2 ;
} 3>&1 | tag STDOUT 3>&- ;
```

This should give the following output:

```
[STDOUT] std1
[STDERR] error2
[STDERR] error3
[STDOUT] std4
```

It works for me in bash and ksh (93u+).

Note that I add "sleep 0.1" between command in order to preserve line order in that case.