# Merge stdout and stderr, and create copies of each separately

Tags: bash

My goal is best explained by example.  To start, here's 
a function that will produce sample output, on both stdout and 
stderr:

```
output() {
  printf '%s\n' 1 2
  printf '%s\n' errA errB 1>&2
  printf '%s\n' 3 4
}
```

If you run this by itself, both streams will be printed to terminal in the order of execution:

```
$ output
1
2
errA
errB
3
4
```

Now this function is simply a placeholder to represent the output (stdout and stderr) 
of some arbitrary script we wish to log.  Specifically, we want to create three
different logs:

1. The combined, execution-order output of stdout and stderr (ie, the output above).
2. Just the stdout output
3. Just the stderr output

The closest solution I've come up with is this:

```
$ { output > >(tee out) 2> >(tee err >&2); } > both 2>&1
$ ls
both  err  out
$ cat both
errA
errB
1
2
3
4
$ cat out
1
2
3
4
$ cat err
errA
errB
```

As you can see, the `out` and `err` files are as desired, but the combined
file `both` does not maintain the order of execution.

Is there a way to create the 3 desired log files simultaneously?

As a bonus question, is order-of-execution output actually guaranteed 
when running the `output` function on its own?  I have tried running 
many times, and the mixed stdout and stderr in the terminal is always
the same, and in the correct order.  But that is not the same thing
as a guarantee.

Comment: See (possible duplicate?) [Redirecting stderr and stdout separately to a function in a bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418705/73093) and weep.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Thanks.  I feared this might be so.  Re: my bonus question, is the order execution guaranteed in that case because they're both in the same process at that point?  Separately, as a workaround, is there any way to distinguish what is coming from stderr vs stdout without redirecting and thus breaking them up?  Or is there a kind of Heisenberg principle at work, where the order is lost as soon as you can look at them independently?

Comment: Output order could be subject to internal buffering within the application but is probably reliable on the same system (no scheduling issues, just buffer sizes, and the application may avoid it regardless). I don't know about distinguishing the streams; last time I concluded the answer was no but I'm not absolutely certain about that.

Comment: By default, `stdout` is buffered, and `stderr` is not, so no, output order is *not* guaranteed.  Indeed, when output is large, it's normal to see an error message before the regular output that lead to it.  So we cannot do what you ask in a way that preserves item #1, because item #1 never existed in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the comment

Comment: There are no ordering guarantees on two separate files; you would have to make sure that stdout is completely flushed all the way to all the (`tee`d) outputs before writing anything to stderr — and vice versa. Possible ways to keep messages in original order: (a) Merge the two streams beforehand in the program that produces them and add stdout / stderr tags (text or binary) to each message, then log them together and/or split them apart as needed. (b) Add non-decreasing nanosecond clock timestamps to each message and “sort” afterwards (using a small heap-based sorting window, not a full sort).

Comment: [Here’s a very distantly related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68837191/8584929) Quite off-topic here (or just too different), but some of those ideas *might* be useful.